# Jones polynomial of a knot in terms of its Seifert matrix

Tags: differential-topology, mathematical-physics, 3d, knot-theory, knot-invariants

It is well known that the *Alexander polynomial* of a knot can be written in terms of the Seifert matrix of the knot by a simple relationship $$\Delta(t)=\det(V^T-tV),$$ where $t$ is a formal variable and $V$ is the Seifert matrix of the given knot.

**Question:** Is it possible to write the *Jones polynomial* of a knot in terms of $V$ as in the Alexander polynomial case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be pleasantly surprised if there were.

Comment: Cross-posted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442585/jones-polynomial-of-a-knot-in-terms-of-its-seifert-matrix

Comment: It would be nice to have some context for the question… but I think closing the question is a bit harsh? This question is certainly at the right level for math.stackexchange

Comment: @MoisheKohan I sincerely apologize for the cross-posting. The publication was entirely attributed to my ignorance on good practises at the stack exchange network. I deleted the question at MO.

Comment: Just to let you know. Maybe after the negative answer, you will be interested in The Jones Polynomial from a Goeritz Matrix https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.03082

Comment: Thanks a lot, @knotMJ ! I greatly appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  There are examples of “S-equivalent knots” $K$ and $L$ with different Jones polynomials. (You can take $K$ to be the unknot, if you like, to simplify the proof.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise answer. Also thanks for the kind orientation on how to proceed with the cross-posting of this question at mathoverflow. The cross-post was entirely do to my ignorance about good practices. I will not happen again.